# mvc contrib pager question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

Let us say I have a bunch of checkboxes above my grid. posting their values (if selected) is no problem. I can also manipulate the the query strings that the pager uses for a GET request like this:

```
Html.Pager(Model.AssetsPagedList)
        .First("First")
        .Last("Last")
        .Next("Next")
        .Previous("Previous")
          .Link(currentPage => Url.Action("Browse", new {  
            page = currentPage,
            searchTerm = Model.SearchModel.SearchTerm,
            excludedWords = Model.SearchModel.ExcludedWords,
            minPrice = Model.SearchModel.MinPrice,
            maxPrice = Model.SearchModel.MaxPrice,
            locationId = Model.SearchModel.LocationId,  
            catalogId = Model.SearchModel.CatalogId
        }))
```

I am just wondering whether I can use the pager in a POST scenario. I guess on could change the links dynamically (after the checkboxes are changed) using javascript/jquery and still use GET. Or could change the links to submit buttons for POSTs. Did anyone use the pager like this?

Thanks.

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links cannot send POST requests. Only HTML forms or AJAX can. So either AJAXify your links or use forms with submit buttons (for this you will need to write a custom pager because the one used in MVCContrib uses links).

As far as AJAXifying the links is concerned:

```
$('.pagination a').live('click', function() {
    $.post(this.href, function(result) {
        // do something with the result
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I know that but you can make a submit button look like a link (-: I use this for delete operations ...

Comment: @csetzkorn, of course that you can. You could use a `<input type="image" src="foo.png" />` where foo.png looks like a link. I think that there might also be some other nice CSS techniques to achieve this. Unfortunately I am not a specialist with CSS. For me an image looks and works just fine :-) I tend to write semantically correct markup and leave the *look and feel part* to the designers.

Comment: Thanks as usual you answer is very good. Might use your comment as this avoids javascript ...